# Find all the automorphisms of $(\mathbb{R},<)$, the real numbers with the usual ordering

Tags: logic, real-numbers

Find all the automorphisms of $(\mathbb{R},<)$, the real numbers with the usual ordering

Obviously the identity mapping,

$\iota : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \iota(r) = r$

and the mapping of changing the sign doesn't though because say

$\phi_{neg} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, defined as   $\phi_{neg}(r) = -r$ then for $a < b$, its not true that $\phi_{neg}(a) < \phi_{neg}(b)$

I think the identity would be the only one

Comment: what's your definition of an automorphism here?

Comment: Autmorphisms as what? Ordered field? Field? Ordered set?

Comment: If you are only preserving $<$, then any shift will work.

Comment: Surely he means automorphisms as an ordered set, since he explicitly writes the structure $(\mathbb R,<)$.

Comment: There's also the possibility of ordered field, @AndreasBlass, which yields quite the different answer.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ has extra structure so he could be asking for an automorphism as an ordered group for example.

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes as an ordered set

Comment: @oliverjones you can shift, you can expand, you can shrink, and you can combine these operations to get uncountably many isomorphisms.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli your $\hat{\phi}$ does not have to be onto.

Comment: @James, you *litterally* got me $1$ second before deleting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any strictly increasing bijection is an ordered-set automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}, <)$. The only requirements are that $f$ is bijective and $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)$. This is an extremely large set of functions (I believe they are all at least continuous though).

Comment: Yes, they are all continuous. Proof: the inverse image of a closed interval is a closed interval.

Comment: @aes that's not sufficient to prove continuity. However, the inverse image of an open interval is an open interval, and since the open intervals form a basis for the topology this implies continuity.

Comment: @DanielRust this is true, however closed intervals do not "generate" the collection of closed sets in any sense as open intervals do the open sets. For example, noncompact closed sets cannot be expressed as finite unions of arbitrary intersections of closed intervals (to give some meaning to "generate").

Comment: @MattSamuel Non-compact closed intervals are still closed intervals, and the simple proof that works for closed intervals is the same for the non-compact ones. (And then any open interval is the complement of the union of at most two closed intervals.) But, yes, you could nearly as quickly prove the result for open intervals instead.

Comment: @aes closed intervals have two endpoints and hence are always compact. I assume by "noncompact closed interval" you mean a half open interval that is a closed set.